# How can use button open web browser

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I successfully create an index address link on the main list screen?

[github source](https://github.com/BM-LSM/my_land)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `url_launcher` package in some `onPressed`or `onTap` property:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

...

ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Open Google'),
  onPressed: () => launch('https://google.com'),
);
```

In your code's listview, that could be used like

```dart
return ListView.builder(
    primary: false,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data[i].yadmNm),
            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[i].sidoNm),
            trailing: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                    // Launch the Google Maps website to the location of this item
                    launch('https://www.google.com/maps/?q=${data[i].XPosWgs84},${data[i].YPosWgs84}');
                    // e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/?q=51.50,0.00
                },
                child: Text('지도보기'),
            ),
        );
    },
);
```

Though depending on your platform, I would recommend using `geo` intents to launch Apple Maps on iOS or any maps app on Android instead, providing it the location (using String interpolation again). More info on that over on Google's own website:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#intent_requests

Comment: Thank you for answer.
A single link is possible with the above content, but the link for each index cannot be resolved.

Comment: You should be able to use the `ListView.builder` (as you already are!) to create a different callback for each list item. I'll update my answer to show how that could look like in your code